# Carga lingüística de "pariendo chayotes"

Tags: méxico, coloquialismos

Sea el siguiente ejemplo:

> Tengo demasiado trabajo, no sé como voy a hacer todo, estoy pariendo chayotes.

Siempre me ha gustado la expresión *pariendo chayotes*, se me hace muy chistosa. ¿Qué tan grosero es decirla en México?

Los chayotes son una especie de calabaza espinosa.

Comment: Suena muy feo. ¿Qué son los chayotes?

Comment: Son una especie de calabaza espinosa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que preguntaste por la carga linguística de la expresión, deja te lo pongo con **peras y manzanas**.

**Parir chayotes** se encuentra en la confluecia de dos corrientes expresivas del habla popular mexicana que son *la comida* y las *referecias a los procesos biológicos*. Aunque no vienen juntos siempre, a menudo coinciden porque muchas de las partes del cuerpo humano (o procesos biológicos) tienen un paralelo con la comida o la cocina. Para ejemplificar, podemos tomar la siguiente historia.

> Legaba Juan a la chamba **fresco como una lechuga** cuando se encontró a su compañero José que andaba como **agua para chocolate** frente al edificio.
> — ¿Qué traes José? te veo muy **enchilado**
> — El jefe que me hace **sudar sangre** y ya me llenó el **buche de piedritas**
> — Pues como no me hables **al chile**, no te voy a entender.
> — En la junta de la mañana, el **hijo de la tostada** se puso muy **de blanquillos** a llenarme de **calabaza** frente a todos los compañeros.
> — ¿Y por qué te regañó?
> — Porque como estamos atrasados con el cierre; la agarró conmigo dando a entender que me la paso **tragando moscas** todo el día.
> — ¡Ah que **jijo del maiz**! ¿Y qué pasó desupés?
> — Pues pensé — **que trague mas pinole el que tenga mas saliva** — y que empiezo a darle referencia de mi trabajo. Yo creo que se apenó porque se puso a **tragar camotes** un rato. Al final de la junta, me dijo que le habían ido a **calentar la tatema**. Yo solo le pedí que me dejara salir media hora y aquí estoy.
> — ¡Qué mal **hongo**! ¿Y quién habrá sido el chismoso?
> — La verdad, **me importa un cacahuate**. Como sabes, soy el único sostén de la familia; así que solo me importa que no me vayan a **dar calabazas**.
> — Lo bueno de todo es que solo fue una confusión. Pero me voy o yo también saldré regañado. Te veo al rato.
> — !Al ratón le gusta el queso!

En cuanto a que tan groseras son las expresiones, el hecho de usar una alegoría de este tipo (sobre todo hacer paralelo con la comida), reduce la crudeza de lenguaje de una manera muy importante sin llegar a hacerlo lenguaje estándar. Por lo tanto, como todo lenguaje popular, el uso de expresiones de este tipo requiere tacto y cautela.

Answer (score 3):

La frase *pariendo chayotes* hace referencia a que algo "es muy difícil, requiere mucho esfuerzo y trabajo". Es un término chusco/cómico.

Esta expresión creo que proviene de la acción en las mujeres de "parir un hijo", quiero decir con esto que una mujer sufre de mucho dolor cuando "da a luz" un hijo de forma natural, entonces ahora imagina que en lugar de "parir" un ser humano, lo que está pariendo sea un chayote.

Para los que no sepan qué es un chayote, dejo aquí una imagen, para que veáis el esfuerzo, trabajo y dolor que sería parir uno.

[image: Chayote]

Imagen extraída de: http://www.agrolatin.com/images/chayote%20con%20espina.jpg

Answer (score 0):

El significado depende del contexto. Ver por ejemplo la siguiente cita de Arreola:

> Carrancistas y villistas nos traían a salto de mata desde Colima a Guadalajara, pariendo chayotes.
> *La feria. Arreola, Juan José (Ed. Joaquín Mortiz, México 1963).*

Comment: Buenas, Alfonso, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Y cuáles son los otros significados posibles? ¿Qué significa exactamente en la cita que aportas?